# How to pass a static method reference in JAVA?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, method-reference

I have a class called `Numbers`, and inside some `static` methods which represent basic operations such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, division.

Now I want to create a static method called `operate` which receives a reference to the previous `static` methods explained. How can I do that?

```
public class Numbers {
    public static long addition(long x, long y) {
         return x + y;
    }

    public static long operate(/*a reference to a static method in Numbers class*/,
                               long x, long y) {
         return reference(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: method names should be verbs, like "add" instead of "addition".

Answer (score 11):

You are likely looking for a `BinaryOperator<T>` which represents an operation upon two operands of the same type `T` returning a result of the same type `T` as the operands:

```
public static long operate(BinaryOperator<Long> binaryOperator, long x, long y) {
    return binaryOperator.apply(x, y);
}
```

As you can see, there aren't any method references in the method declaration. You should define types of parameters there, later you will be deciding what *actual parameters* to pass during the method invocation:

an anonymous class:

```
operate(new BinaryOperator<Long>() {
    public @Override Long apply(Long l1, Long l2) {
        return Numbers.addition(l1, l2);
    }
}, 2, 2);
```

a lambda expression:

```
operate((l1, l2) -> Numbers.addition(l1, l2), 2, 2);
```

or a method reference:

```
operate(Numbers::addition, 2, 2);
```

Comment: If all the operations are really on primitive `long`s, it might be better to use a  [LongBinaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/LongBinaryOperator.html) instead to avoid boxing.